# Requiring one of two sets of parameters in function based on first parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, args, keyword-argument

I have a function which has two main parameters that determine the rest of the required parameters.

For example, if

`main = 'a'`

Then it requires parameters `q`, `w`, `e`

But if `main = 'b'`

Then it requires parameters `a`, `s`, `d`

To be passed as arguments to a function.

I understand that I could use `**kwargs` and add an if statement based on `main` to choose the optional parameters, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without optional arguments, as the entire set of parameters is required based on `main`.

What is the most pythonic way of dealing with this without having two functions?

The kwargs solution is below to make the question more reproducible:

```
def function_(main, **kwargs):
    if main == 'a':
        q = kwargs.get('q')
        w = kwargs.get('w')
        e = kwargs.get('e')
        return q * w * e
    if main == 'b':
        a = kwargs.get('a')
        s = kwargs.get('s')
        d = kwargs.get('d')
        return a + d + s
```

Comment: Those are just names, you can use any name you want. Names are bound to objects.

Comment: @heemayl Could you expand on that? I just updated the question to clarify that different results need to be returned. My actual code is more complex than just multiplying/adding though, it calls different functions based on `main` value.

Comment: What is the reason against two functions?

Comment: @MartinUeding In my actual code, it would lead to a lot of redundancy. This is simplified to make it reproducible, though it conveys the idea of what I am looking for.

Comment: Two well named and defined functions make code maintenance easier instead of a single function with a huge if/elif/else block... There's nothing wrong with two or more functions here...

Comment: @JonClements Even if it leads to redundant portions of the function?

Comment: @Jack well... if there's a couple that are fairly redundant - maybe that's suitable for a function that checks a couple of criteria... but you don't need one big function that tries everything...

Comment: If there's a common set of stuff functions do - then you move that into another function and put the common stuff in that that the functions need that they share... etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
def function_(main, *args, **kwargs):
    if main == 'a':
        q, w, e = args
    elif main == 'b':
        a, s, d = args
```

Or perhaps have two functions that you relay to:

```
def function_(main, *args, **kwargs):
    if main == 'a':
        function_a_(*args, **kwargs)
    elif main == 'b':
        function_b_(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I would challenge the need for this construction and instead try to do this with normal functions with normal parameters.